Bad magic number in super-block on external HD after multiple power outages—still OK to use?
I have a computer at home that I use as a file server, using Nextcloud. Every computer at home is Ubuntu/etx4. I've had multiple outages recently in the neighborhood, and I think the sudden shutdowns have messed up my external hard drive. It doesn't stay mounted, and folders seem to disappear and reappear on it. I checked the filesystem using Ubuntu's 'Disk' app and it said the disk is fine.
However, running fsck /dev/sdb returns:
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sdb

OK,so I ran e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdb:
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

I ran e2fsck -b 8193 and got the same result. Here are my questions:

What should be my next step? Testdisk? Something else?
This is a pretty new USB hard drive from Western Digital—a few months old. I could clone an image of the data, but I already have backups of this data elsewhere and could also just wipe the HD, start fresh, and move the data back over. But I don't know if it's safe to keep things backed up on this HD anymore. How do I determine whether the drive has hardware damage?


I would erase and reformat the drive if you have the data elsewhere, and purchase a UPS to provide either dependable power, time to shutdown cleanly, or both.  If you no longer trust the drive, replace it, otherwise reformat and carry on.

Can you show SMART attributes of the disk? It's also worth running a selftest. Sometimes, it's good to rewrite a disk completely (e.g. with zeros), and compare the attributes.

You're using the wrong device (sdb has a partition table, not a file system). Use the correct partition? cat /proc/partitions, blkid, lsblk, smartctl -a, ...

@NikitaKipriyanov I ran the short test and it just said it passed. I'm going to assume this drive is still good and just reformat it.

@frostschutz I ran fsck /dev/sdb1 and got clean, 67655/122093568 files, 107675034/488369920 blocks. So it's a mystery. Is there even anything wrong with this drive? Maybe the USB ports on my computer are failing.

@NikitaKipriyanov the long test also passed, no errors. It seems that this disk has a bad magic number and everything else about it is fine. I think I just need to know how to fix the superblock problem.

@frostschutz pointed me in the right direction. I guess I should have been using fsck on /dev/sdb1 and not /dev/sdb. The 'bad magic number' response is because fsck is trying to operate on a partition and instead finding a GUID partition table.
This means that I have never found an error with this drive—not using gnome-disks 'check filesystem', not using fsck, and not using the short or long s.m.a.r.t. self-test. Therefore, the problem with the drive disconnecting and folders disappearing must have something to do with the computer trying to read the drive, and not with the drive itself.
So now the question is how to troubleshoot the computer and determine why it's having trouble reading the external drive or keeping it mounted.
Another point I read which might be useful to others:

Ext3, Ext4, ZFS, btrfs, xfs and all modern FS are 100% consistent after a crash or system reset.

So I might be operating on an outdated assumption that system crashes damage hard drives. Since this external drive is not an SSD, I would think the head crash is still a risk and the hardware could fail that way. But maybe this is also outdated thinking, I'm not sure.

Ext3, Ext4, ZFS, btrfs, xfs — I wouldn't be that sure. For instance, ext3/ext4 will be only safe if you're having data journaling enabled, which is not by default. Else, you may have consistent filesystem, e.g. see all the files, see correct sizes, but the actual data in files still can be damaged. As of now, I'd only trust ZFS that much. Hopefully, upcoming bcachefs will be also safe, because if it's journal and COW nature.

Well I ran sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdd1 | grep features and the results say Filesystem features: has_journal...however, I have this HDD as attached storage in Nextcloud, which I use to sync my files across different computers. Once I remounted my HDD, Nextcloud started syncing the files from drive, through my LAN, replacing local files. This means Nextcloud thought the files had changed, which they should not have. This made me nervous so I immediately disabled file sync on all my computers.

has_journal still doesn't mean it does journalling, especially data journalling. It only means some extents were allocated for use as a journal. There's a mount option that switches it, and it's not enabled by default. There's even a setting in a filesystem which changes the default value for this mount option to be enabled, but again, it's not set by default and you can override it from the command line anyway. You can even mount a file system which has_journal in such a way won't use it for anything (however, that's not a default this time; metadata is journalled by default).

Ok, my point was, you can't predict how exactly something is going to operate when it failed. The journal and whatever else enhances the chances of data survival in case of most common types of failures, but doesn't guarantee it for every case. Nothing will. Do backups.

try run with -p option for automatic correction (no additional questions)
# fsck.ext2 -p /dev/sdb

